# Emberjs Create many records or createRecord in a loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So I have run into a few complex ember problems I can't seem to find an answer for anywhere, and although this may get answered late hopefully it helps someone.

**The use case for this situation**

I am creating a product and inside this product it has an image that belongs to it. it also has title and the description. But more unique it has many variations of this t-shirt, it comes in small, med, and large and each variation has its own quantity and price. 
So when creating a product I have to create the product fields, image fields, and many variations! up to 3 to be exact. and then when I submit the form the controller handles all 3 variations and the form.

**Here is what I did. after I run my validate function**

```
$('.variation').manageSize('destroy');//Grabs array in localstorage containing the objects
    function create(){
                console.log('Create the product now');
                 var product = prop.store.createRecord('product', {
                    name: $("input[name='name']").val(),
                    color: null,
                    description:$("textarea[name='description']").val(),
                    createdAt:''
                });
                var base64 = $('.cropper').cropper("getDataURL");
                var image = prop.store.createRecord('image',{
                    imgSrc:base64.attr('src')   
                });
                var variation;
                for(var i = 0; i < variationCheck.length; i++) {
                console.log(variationCheck.length);
                    window[variation+i] = prop.store.createRecord('variation',{
                        size: variationCheck[i].size,
                        quantity: variationCheck[i].quantity,
                        price: variationCheck[i].price,
                        shippingPrice: variationCheck[i].shipping
                    }); 
                    window[variation+i].save();
                }   


            // Save the new model

                image.save();
                product.save();
                $('.variation').manageSize('destroy');
    }
},
```

Im getting an error probably because this should not work at all
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'NaN' of [object global]
But I figure even if there is bad code I cant find anything on createRecord many times in one controller. Or even how to properly create a record and reflect how it looks in the model.

**PRODUCT MODEL**

```
Ember.Product = DS.Model.extend({
shop: DS.belongsTo('store'),
name: DS.attr('string'),
color: DS.attr('string'),
description: DS.attr('string'),
images: DS.hasMany('image', {embedded: 'always'}),
token: DS.hasMany('token', {embedded: 'always'}),
variations: DS.hasMany('variation', {embedded: 'always'}),
productCategory: DS.belongsTo('productCategory'),
likes: DS.hasMany('like',{embedded: 'always'}),
createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
updatedAt: DS.attr('date'),
publishedAt: DS.attr('date'),
postDate: DS.attr('date'),
postCounter: DS.attr('number'),
published: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's likely more than one error here, but for the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'NaN' of [object global]

The issue is that you do

```
var variation;
for(var i = 0; i < variationCheck.length; i++) {
    window[variation+i] = ...
```

variation is undefined, so variation+i is NaN, so you are trying to assign to window[NaN] repeatedly.